# A big tennis tournament

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

We are organizing a tennis tournament. 
The rules are the default ones.

- 2 players play against each other
- the winner advances to the next round
- this goes on until one player is crowned champion.

1000 players signed up for the tournament.
**How many matches will our tournament have?**
(please provide an explanation for the number you find)

Bonus (my appreciation): how many matches will there be for $n$ players?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In every game that will be played, there is one loser. Because you need $1$ champion (and $999$ losers), you need

> 999 games. More general, for any tournament with $n$ players, you need $n-1$ games.

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is **`999`**.
>  For any number `n` it will be *`n-1`*.

**Explanation**

Since this is a knockout round.At the end of each round, half players are getting eliminated. 
Let `N = 2^k` where *N* is the total number of Players.

In First Round, We will have `N/2` matches, in second round `N/4` matches. So, at the end of last round we will have `1` match.

Total number of matches = `N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ....2 + 1` which is a standard Geometric Progression Problem.

The Sum will be `1*(2^k - 1)/(2-1) = 2^k - 1 = N-1`

Similarly, You can generalize this to any 'N'.

For Generalizing it for any `N`, Remember that we can break any `N` in powers of `2`.

Ex- I can write **`1000 = 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 8`**.
Now, Doing as above, We will have **`511+ 255 + 127 + 63 + 31 + 7 = 994`** matches. We will be left with 6 people.

Similarly, `6 = 2 + 2 + 2` , Then we will have 3 more matches i.e 997 and left with 3 people.

Now for `3` people, split as `2` and `1` which will take 2 matches.
The total number of matches will be `994 + 3 + 2 = 999.`

Now, You can generalize it.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: but what if N is not $2^k$ ?

Comment: Sorry for poor formating. I am new here.
You can always break any number in sum of powers of two. Like For 1000, I can write **1000 = 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 8**.
Now, We will have **511+ 255 + 127 + 63 + 31 + 7 = 994** matches. We will be left with 6 people. 
Similarly, 6 = 2 + 2 + 2 , Then we will have 3 more matches i.e 997 and left with 3 people.

Similarly, For 3 people, there will be 2 more matches. Hence, The total matches will be 999.